# Data do not correspond from combo box to textbox

Tags: c#, database, windows

I am trying to have the data from my combo box to correspond to my textboxes after clicking them. But it is not working. Need help, below is my code

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try 
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection; 
                string query = "select * from ExerciseData where FirstName='"+ comboBox1 .Text+"'";

                command.CommandText = query;


                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
                while (reader.Read()) 
                {
                    EIDTB.Text = reader["EID"].ToString();
                    FirstNameTB.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    LastNameTB.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    CountryTB.Text = reader["Country"].ToString();

                }

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

instead of

```
comboBox1.Text
```

The Text property is if text is typed into the combo box, selected item is what item has been selected